# What to do in order to return True or False instead of the actual distance of the circle?

Tags: python

The code below is returning the actual distance of the circle. But I want to return True or False.
This is supposed to return False as the actual distance is less than the circle's radius. Why is it not returning False? What should I do?

```
class Point:
 x = 0
 y = 0
class Circle:
 center = Point ()
 radius = 0

def point_in_circle(c, p):
  w = math.sqrt((p.x - c.center.x)**2 + (p.y - c.center.y)**2)
  return w
  if w < c.radius:
   return True
  else:
   return False

c = Circle()
c.center.x, c.center.y, c.radius = 0, 0, 1

p = Point()
p.x, p.y = 1, 1

print (point_in_circle(c, p))
```

Comment: It's not returning `True` or `False` because you're explicitly returning `w`???

Comment: And BTW `return w < c.radius` would do the job of 4 of your line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a `return w` in point_in_circle() and then a condition
by the way you can just `return w < c.radius` - no need to do the if